# Google Calendar: Changed formatting when changing the source of the iframe to display another timezone

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In my website, I am displaying a google calendar using an iframe that I obtained from settings of my google calendar. The iframe tag looks like:

```html
<iframe id="ll-calendar-iframe" src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=03d500sqj7smu2ho2on9set69k%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FToronto&amp;color=%231aa3ff&amp;bgcolor=%23f9cf00&amp;showTz=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;mode=WEEK" style="border:solid 2px #182C57; border-radius: 7px;" width="1200" height="700" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And the calendar with the formatting looks like:
[image]

For my website, I will have users from different timezones accessing it and I want to display the calendar for that particular timezone. For that, I am changing the source of the iframe with that particular timezone but in doing so, the whole formatting of the calendar is affected. When I try to do it this way:

```js
document.getElementById("ll-calendar-iframe").src = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=03d500sqj7smu2ho2on9set69k%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Asia%2FCalcutta&amp;color=%231aa3ff&amp;bgcolor=%23f9cf00&amp;showTz=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;mode=WEEK";
```

the whole calendar changes and doesn't look the same as it did before. All the customizations that I had done before like removing the print button, the timezone from the bottom, removing the week, month and agenda tags are gone. The calendar changes to look like this:
[image]

While changing the source, I just updated the timezone in the calendar link and I changed nothing else. I'm not sure why the whole look of the calendar changes. I would really appreciate some help on this.